# mysql left join to table with multiple rows on min id to ensure single row returned

Tags: mysql, database, join

```
item
id=1..
id=2..
id=3..

item_image
id=1, item_id=1, image_id=1
id=2, item_id=2, image_id=2
id=3, item_id=2, image_id=3

image
id=1
id=2
id=3
```

With the following SQL I'm getting a duplicate record for itemid 2. One with image_id=2 and another with image_id= null.

```
 SELECT  i.id iid, im.id, i.summary, i.description, ist.name , item_status, i.enabled, p.price_asked_for, im.thumb_url
 FROM item i
 LEFT JOIN item_status ist
 ON ist.id = i.item_status_id
 LEFT JOIN price p
 ON p.id = i.price_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN item_image ii
 ON i.id = ii.item_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN image im
 ON im.id = ii.image_id
 WHERE i.member_id = 436
  and (im.id =  ( select min(ii2.image_id) from item_image ii2 where      ii.item_id = ii2.item_id) 
    or im.id is null)
```

The item_image may or may not have a matching row.
The image table may have more than 1 matching row.

I'm trying to return the first match in the image table if it's there but null if it is not there.

With the line 'or im.id is null' present I'm ensuring that if there's no matching image then it's ok to return nothing. If i don't have this and there's no image the record won't appear as there's no image.
However with this or null i get both a matching image and a null value. a duplicate.
Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

The expression:

```
(im.id =  (select min(ii2.image_id)
           from item_image ii2
           where ii.item_id = ii2.item_id)  or
 im.id is null)
```

*cannot* be responsible for returning duplicates.  At most one of the two expressions can every be true.  Why?  Because if `im.id` is NULL, then the first will always fail (comparisons to `NULL` are not true).  If `im.id` is *not* NULL, then the second fails.